# Looking for mobile first software that manages employee payroll + time tracking

Tags: time-management, business-intelligence

I'm about to hire my first employee and I'm looking for a piece of software that will allow me to track the employee's working hours, their tasks, and their salary.

It should be mobile first and relatively cheap.

Thank you for recommendations.

Comment: Welcome Mary!  If you will, please edit your question to specify the operating system and price range.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [Deputy](https://www.deputy.com/) for a year now, exclusively via mobile app (iPhone, always latest iOS).

We use it as a payroll & hours management platform, so it should meet your requirements.

I don't know what is cheap for you, but it runs us about $4 per staff member per month, which is competitively priced in the current market compared to competitors.

Hope this helps!